# Confusing question on exponents and algebra.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was going through some sample papers of math, and I found this question which I cant solve:

If $abc=1$, find $1/(1+a+b^{-1})+1/(1+b+c^{-1})+1/(1+c+a^{-1})$.

Please help me with this.... I have spent almost 3 hours on this question...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have reached a kind of situation like this: $b/(b+ab+1) + c/(c+bc+1)+a(a+ac+1)$

Comment: And many more situations, but every time I come back to the original expression, its a kind of loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac 1{1+a+b^{-1}}=\frac b{b+ab+1}=\frac b{1+b+c^{-1}}$$

The last equation follows because, $ab=1/c$.

In a similar manner,
$$\frac 1{1+c+a^{-1}}=\frac a{a+ac+1}=\frac a{a+b^{-1}+1}=\frac{ab}{1+b+c^{1}}$$

So, putting this altogether gives

$$\begin{align}
& \frac 1{1+a+b^{-1}}+\frac 1{1+b+c^{-1}}+\frac 1{1+c+a^{-1}} \\
= & \frac b{1+b+c^{-1}}+\frac 1{1+b+c^{-1}}+\frac{ab}{1+b+c^{-1}}\\
= & \frac{1+b+c^{-1}}{1+b+c^{-1}}=1.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat plodding, but nonetheless effective, approach is simply to eliminate one of variables, say letting $c=(ab)^{-1}$, and then simplify the fractions:

$$\begin{align}
{1\over1+a+b^{-1}}+{1\over1+b+c^{-1}}+{1\over1+c+a^{-1}}
&={1\over1+a+b^{-1}}+{1\over1+b+ab}+{1\over1+(ab)^{-1}+a^{-1}}\\\\
&={b\over b+ab+1}+{1\over1+b+ab}+{ab\over ab+1+b}\\\\
&={1+b+ab\over1+b+ab}\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$